# Limiting the total memory usage of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I know that with `postgresql.conf` I can limit the memory usage of specific parts of PostgreSQL, like shared memory or worker memory, but is there a way to limit the total memory usage of the PostgreSQL server? I failed to find a configuration property that does that...

BTW, I'm going to need to run it on a Windows Server 2008 machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean "total" memory? It's the sum of what you allocate to the various pools.

So, in short... don't set the various pools/buffers too big and that's your total memory limit.

Comment: I see... I was hoping there is some limit I could set and rest assured that PostgreSQL will never pass it, but I guess that will have to do. Are there any pitfalls I should watch out for when setting those memory limits?

Comment: work_mem is max memory usable by an individual sort or other memory intensive operation (hash ops etc).  Each query can have o, 1, or more of these ops.  Assuming your average query has 2 or fewer sorts etc you can get a gross idea of max memory a heavily used machine might see is max_connections * work_mem * 2, give or take.  Individual postgresql backends only use about 6MB so unless you have a very high max_connections individual backends, without sorts etc, don't add up to much.

Comment: Be aware that less is sometimes more, so don't just blindly increase all those numbers, as many are actually performance penalties if set to excessive levels.

Comment: No information on which pools exist, how they might overlap, what their defaults are or anything else useful. -1.

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL does not have any global limit that you can set. Instead you configure `shared_buffers` (usually around 25% - 50% of the total RAM you intend to grant for PostgreSQL), `max_connections` (how many parallel client connections you need, try to keep this as low as possible, maybe use PgPool or pgbouncer) and `work_mem`; the actual memory usage is roughly `shared_buffers` + `max_connections` * `work_mem` * `N`, where `N` depends on your average query complexity. If you only do simple selects, `N` will be 1. If you do lots of sorted subqueries and complex multi-table joins you should assume `N` is somewhere between 4 and 10. Default value for `work_mem` is 4 MB and you shouldn't reduce it unless you know that you cannot have even that much. In my experience, if you need to set `work_mem` higher than 16-32 MB you probably should improve your queries instead.

If you have lots of parallel *serialized* transactions you might need to push `max_connections` to artificially high number to allow enough row locks to be taken to get high performance. (PostgreSQL scales the amount of locks according to `max_connections` and if your transactions need a lot of locks the default scaling might not be enough and PostgreSQL will start converting row locks to table level locks which will cause more serialized transactions to rollback. However, do not mindlessly scale `max_connections` too high because PostgreSQL constantly reserves memory for the max lock count it has been configured to support. Expect to see performance problems if you need more than 4 million parallel locks – that is, overlapping transactions reading or writing over 4 million rows in total. Note that sequential table scanning over big tables have to read lots of rows so you want proper indexes!

Note that if you need to conserve memory, setting `shared_buffers` and `work_mem` to low values will allow PostgreSQL to work within the limits you need, but the performance will suffer. I think the minimum possible is `shared_buffers = 128 KB` and `work_mem = 64 KB`. However, as PostgreSQL runs each backend child as separate OS level process you usually end up spending at least 1-4 MB per backend in any case so you really want to limit parallel client connections if you want to go under 4 MB per connection. For example, `pgbouncer` would be one good option. In practice, I wouldn't recommend setting `shared_buffers` less than 12 MB or `work_mem` less than 1 MB. If you truly cannot afford that, you might need to create a fully custom design that doesn't use SQL database at all. Or try using e.g. SQLite.

Comment: Also, if you're running PostgreSQL version 12 or lesser, increasing work_mem can result in triggering a bug that causes potentially unlimited memory usage, for details, see https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/285423/29183